# open source projects in javascript 

Tags: javascript

I mainly do javascript coding , I am doing javascript coding from last 6 months. I feel, to improve my knowledge I have to get involved in open source projects. Where can I find good open source projects for starters. I am mainly looking for javascript and web services related projects or browser based. Which is the best place to start with ? Anybody in stackoverflow is starting open source projects or any opensource projects u know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In all honesty, I would encourage you to start working with jQuery Plugins. That is a wealth of them online that you can download, modify, and provide to the community of developers. It's a large community, with enormous potential, and a great opportunity for you to not only gain a better understanding of Javascript, but also a way to gain some recognition.

Comment: I totaly agree and what I could sugest you is to work on the DatePicker plugin. And the selection of date range.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, only thing is in my work I heavily use prototype framework, switching to Jquery might be lil difficult.

Answer (score 0):

http://github.com/languages/JavaScript